# mysql select count(*) versus select * - why different number of rows

Tags: mysql, count

I have two queries:

1st:

```
select count(*) 
from table1 s1 
INNER JOIN table2 s2 on s1.id=s2.id
```

2nd:

```
select * 
from table1 s1 
INNER JOIN table2 s2 on s1.id=s2.id
```

1st gives 36996 rows according to phpmyadmin
2nd gives 67365 rows

id is a unique column

why aren't they giving the same # of rows?

Comment: are you running those queries against same database?

Comment: @rahul yes..... same query i just replace \* with count(\*) and gives different result. i noticed also if i add where id > 0 gives same result as count(\*).  where id <=0 gives zero results. bug in phpmyadmin?